# ASP.net Image.ImageUrl

Tags: asp.net, authorization, credentials, imageurl

maybe someone can point me in the right direction (:

How do I use the ".ImageUrl" if the targeted image requires authorization to be viewed? How can I pass the credentials?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: Thank you very much!
It was just IE behaving like a spoiled brat,
Tested on Firefox, works like a charm (:

Comment: I deleted my comment about user/password passing in URLs, because a) it's considered a bad idea, and b) it's not supported everywhere.  So I would ask: how does the image source expect people to view the images?  Do they have a sign-in page?  Or do you get a Windows sign-in message box when you attempt to access it?